# Present subjunctive maps to present or future in English?

Tags: subjuntivo

I'm studying the present subjunctive, and it often appears to translate to two meanings in English. Sentences like this:

> No hay nada que funcione.   (Present subjunctive of *functionar*.)

can mean both these in English:

> There is nothing that will work.
> There is nothing that works.

Is that correct? If they are both possible, is a native speaker more likely to hear it as one or the other?  Is there a good way to differentiate or emphasize one of the meanings? Maybe this:

> No hay nada que vaya a funcionar.  (Sort of like a future subjunctive.)
> No hay nada que esté funcionando.

Comment: Google, Apple, Bing are translating the "will work" sentence with "funcione". They can be wrong, but usually they're good with short sentences.

Comment: Ok, I have reconsidered all this in my answer. Please take a look at it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem here is that the English equivalents are ambiguous. When we say *nothing works* we do not just mean that it is not working right now but we imply that it is unlikely to start working in the immediate future. Similarly when we say *nothing will work* we may also be implying that it is not working right now either (although that is less clear).

Answer (score 1):

Context and direction are everything. So going into Spanish, there's this:

There is nothing that **will** work. I've tried everything. No hay nada que funcion**e.**   *will* here is not a future. It implies other things have been tried.

OR
There is nothing that works. Everything is broken. No hay nada que funcione.
This is just a statement of fact in English.

In English, the meanings are slightly different. But only subjunctive works in Spanish for both.

AND

There is nothing that **will work** tomorrow. The machines aren't ready. No hay nada que **funcionará.** That is a predictive idea. So, not subjunctive in Spanish.

Answer (score 1):

"No hay nada que funcione" refers to the present: "There is nothing that works / that is working".

I agree with Lambie that a possible translation is "There is nothing that will work", but here "will" does not indicate future but a typical behavior, as if the person does not expect anything to work because it has been like that for a long time.

To indicate future, we can use the periphrastic "ir a + infinitive", in which case the Spanish will be:

- No hay nada que vaya a funcionar.

With this construction, the present subjunctive will only refer to the future if a future adverbial is explicit in the context, for example:

- No hay nadie que venga mañana. (There's nobody that will come tomorrow / There's nobody coming tomorrow.)

Answer (score 0):

The present subjunctive expresses uncertainty, probability or feelings, and can deal with the present or the near future, but, we could say, in a dubious or subjective way.

Where the indicative mood is concrete and exact, everything related to the subjunctive mood is nonspecific, virtual, and kind of subjective.